# Toggle Service with widget

Tags: android, widget

I stack on this..

So, how can I toggle Service with widget?

To toggle service via my app, I use 
`MyService.toggleService(                                       getApplicationContext(), true);`
and `ToggleButton MyService.setChecked(true);`and off course `settingsWriter.putBoolean("service_running",((ToggleButton) v).isChecked());`

How can I do the same, but from widget?